# RegisterStartupScript method - page OnLoad event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Look at the documentation for both ScriptManager's and ClientScript's RegisterStartupScript method. In the former case, it says:

> The script block that is rendered by the RegisterStartupScript method
>   executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's client
>   onload event is raised. Startup script blocks are located at the
>   bottom of the rendered ASP.NET page just before the  tag.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb310408(v=vs.110).aspx

Whereas, in the latter:

> The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes
>   when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is
>   raised.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

So in the second case, they mention the OnLoad method that raises the Load event of the Page (which is a part of the ASP.NET [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)), not the client's page onload event.

Is it just a mistake in the documentation? Javascript runs on client's side, and that's after all the page lifecycle has completed and the final page has been sent to the client).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, the latter information is a mistake.

The script block is rendered in the pages render event and it's executed by the browser on client side right on parsing.